# How to clean up SQL expression

Tags: informix

The code below compares recv.rcpt_dtim (which is a datetime type) against the current date/time. It calculates an elapsed time resulting in hours and minutes formatted like: "04:22". It took me a while to get it functional, which it is, but it just seems sloppy. Does anyone have any tips to clean it up?

```
TRIM((((CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) to 
SECOND)/3600)::VARCHAR(12) || ':' || CASE WHEN (MOD(MOD(((CURRENT YEAR TO 
MINUTE - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL MINUTE(9) to 
MINUTE)::VARCHAR(12)::INT,60),60))<10 THEN "0" ELSE "" END || 
(MOD(MOD(((CURRENT YEAR TO MINUTE - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL MINUTE(9) 
to MINUTE)::VARCHAR(12)::INT,60),60))::VARCHAR(12))
```

Comment: You might get an answer here, but if you don't, then consider migrating this question to our sister site [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).  Given that your code already works, the question might work better on that site.

Comment: Thank you Tim! :)

Comment: Question asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220003/calculating-elapsed-time) and answered there to with essentially the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Informix 12.10.FC12 Developer Edition I can do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test_time
(
    rcpt_dtim DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
);

INSERT INTO test_time VALUES ( '2019-05-09 10:01:01' );
INSERT INTO test_time VALUES ( '2019-05-09 10:01:59' );
INSERT INTO test_time VALUES ( '2019-05-09 13:01:00' );
INSERT INTO test_time VALUES ( '2019-05-09 15:01:00' );
INSERT INTO test_time VALUES ( '2019-04-02 22:01:00' );

SELECT
    ( CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND - rcpt_dtim )::INTERVAL HOUR(9) TO MINUTE AS elapsed
FROM
    test_time
;


elapsed
  12:47
  12:46
   9:47
   7:47
   0:47
 888:47
```

Comment: Rats! I just produced basically the same expression over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220003/calculating-elapsed-time).  Scouts honour — I hadn't looked here first!  (I used INTERVAL HOUR(4) TO MINUTE and more data, but the net result is essentially the same.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, your answer is much more detailed and complete, so lets say mine is the TL;DR version.

Comment: Works for me — WFM.